# Stardust Bpm Build Failure

Tags: java, maven

I'm Building Stardust bpm Using maven.. On the stage of **tc7-stardust-portal-war** build failure ..

> [INFO] tc7-stardust-portal-war ............................ FAILURE [
>   34.729 s]
>
> [INFO] sysconsole-client .................................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] console-spring-client .............................. SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] Product NLS Bundles ................................ SKIPPED
>
> [INFO] components-build ................................... SKIPPED
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [INFO] Total time: 11:39 min
>
> [INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-25T15:27:38+05:30
>
> [INFO] Final Memory: 157M/411M
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:integration-test
>   (default-integration-test) on project tc7-stardust-portal-war:
>
> [ERROR] Archetype IT 'base' failed: Execution failure: exit code = 1
>
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>
> [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with
>   the command

Comment: So what's your question? The project you're trying to build has a failing integration test.

Comment: how to resolve this error

Comment: Are you sure this error matters to you? If it does, well, you need to fix the failing tests, and I don't think you'll find any ready-made solution for this.

Comment: i research on this error .. using maven fail-safe plugin we can do integration test ..but how to use fail-safe plugin ...in my code ..

Comment: please follow this link https://eclipse.googlesource.com/stardust/org.eclipse.stardust.deploy.jee/+/master/archetypes/tc7-stardust-portal-war/